# How would I avoid extra NULL rows from case statement in new columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, window-functions

So I have a SQL query that is returning multiple rows with null value, I want to duplicate value and get rid off all now. What is the best way to do this? Any ideas?

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         PRS.[Task_id],
         PE_PRJ.[~Project],
         CASE ROLES.[Task_rolename]
             WHEN N'Primary Doc Controller' THEN USERS.[fullname]
         END AS [Primary Doc Controller],
         CASE ROLES.[Task_rolename]
             WHEN N'Construction Manager' THEN USERS.[fullname]
         END AS [Construction Manager],
         CASE ROLES.[Task_rolename]
             WHEN N'Buyer' THEN USERS.[fullname]
         END AS [Buyer],
         CASE 
             WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PE_PRJ.[~Project], ROLES.[Task_rolename] ORDER BY PRS.[createdon]) = COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY PE_PRJ.[~Project], ROLES.[Task_rolename] )
                 THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
         END AS [Latest Assignment Record]
     FROM 
         [Task].[Task_projectresources] PRS
     LEFT JOIN
         [Task].[Task_projects] PRJ ON PRS.[Task_project] =  PRJ.[Task_projectsid]
     LEFT JOIN
         [Task].[Task_roles] ROLES ON PRS.[Task_role] =  ROLES.[Task_rolesid]
     LEFT JOIN
         [Task].[Project] PE_PRJ ON FLOOR(PE_PRJ.[~Project]) = FLOOR(PRJ.[Task_project])
     LEFT JOIN
         [Task].[systemuser] USERS ON PRS.[Task_resource] = USERS.[systemuserid]
     WHERE 
         [~Project] = '19691.0019'
    ) LATEST
WHERE 
    LATEST.[Latest Assignment Record] = '1'
```

Current results

| Task_id | ~Project | Primary Doc Controller | Construction Manager | Buyer | Latest Assignment Record |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 19.2 | NULL | NULL | Brenda | 1 |
| 2 | 19.2 | Garga | NULL | NULL | 1 |
| 3 | 19.2 | NULL | Rus | NULL | 1 |

Desired results

| Task_id | ~Project | Primary Doc Controller | Construction Manager | Buyer | Latest Assignment Record |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 19.2 | Garga | Rus | Brenda | 1 |
| 2 | 19.2 | Garga | Rus | Brenda | 1 |
| 3 | 19.2 | Garga | Rus | Brenda | 1 |

Comment: without the source data and table, this question is very hard to answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use the `MAX` window function on the `CASE` statements, while partitioning by:

- `PE_PRJ.[~Project]`, as an assumption of partition
- `LATEST.[Latest Assignment Record]`, given you're filtering on this field

```
...
,MAX(CASE ROLES.[Task_rolename]
          WHEN N'Primary Doc Controller' THEN USERS.[fullname]
     END) OVER(PARTITION BY PE_PRJ.[~Project], 
                            LATEST.[Latest Assignment Record]) AS [Primary Doc Controller]
,MAX(CASE ROLES.[Task_rolename]
          WHEN N'Construction Manager' THEN USERS.[fullname]
     END) OVER(PARTITION BY PE_PRJ.[~Project],
                            LATEST.[Latest Assignment Record]) AS [Construction Manager]
,MAX(CASE ROLES.[Task_rolename]
          WHEN N'Buyer' THEN USERS.[fullname]
     END) OVER(PARTITION BY PE_PRJ.[~Project],
                            LATEST.[Latest Assignment Record]) AS [Buyer]
...
```